# ESlint error: const keyword is reserved in Brakets ide

Tags: constants, adobe-brackets

I have update [ecmascript-5](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-5) to [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) but it is still showing this error. I cannot understand how to solve it.